# Python - How to compare the content of two list are in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to compare that all the items of list "present" are in the string "line" and all the elements of the list "absent" are NOT in the string "line"

So, having the 2 lists

```
present = ['SYN', 'ACK']
absent = ['RST', 'FIN']
```

And a file with all the TCP flags from here: https://github.com/robcowart/elastiflow/blob/master/logstash/elastiflow/dictionaries/tcp_flags.yml

```
"...
"12": RST-PSH
"13": FIN-RST-PSH
"14": SYN-RST-PSH
"15": FIN-SYN-RST-PSH
"16": ACK
"17": FIN-ACK
"18": SYN-ACK
"19": FIN-SYN-ACK
"20": RST-ACK
"21": FIN-RST-ACK
"22": SYN-RST-ACK
"23": FIN-SYN-RST-ACK
..."
```

I will read the file line by line if all the elements of "present" exist in the line and all the elements of "absent" do NOT exist in the line, then print the line

How should I do it? I imagine recursion or comprehension, but I can not find the way.
thanks

Comment: What is the output you need here? From what I can see all of the strings in `present` and `absent` exist in that `yml` file.

Comment: sorry I forgot, read the file line by line, if all the elements of "present" exist in the line and all the elements of "absent" do NOT exist in the line, then print the line

Comment: If your present and absent lists are not long: `[line for line in file if all(p in line for p in present) and all(a not in line for a in absent)]`

Comment: the power of tremendous logic in a single line! wow great answer @kate-melnykova. Method 1 matching lines: 16 - Exec time: 0.00039768218994140625

Answer (score 4):

```
for line in csv_reader:
    # parse the line and store the flags into a list
    # flags = line.split...

    # the logic to check for present and absent
    is_present = all(elem in flags for elem in present)
    is_absent = not any(elem in flags for elem in absent)
    if is_present and is_absent:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Beautiful. This is about as pythonic as it gets.

Comment: yes beatifull and easy to read!!!. good one @yanxun!  The splitting part added some exec time. Method 2 matching lines: 16 - Exec time: 0.0012302398681640625

Answer (score 1):

```
line="abcee"
present=['abc','cde','fgh']
absent=['bla','ghj']
def AllInLine():
    for i in present:
        if i not in line:
            return False;
    return True;
def NoneInLine():
    for i in absent:
        if i in line:
            return False;
    return True;
```

then if both functions return true you can print the line

Comment: I like it! easy to read logic and applicable to any language. Curiously you won in exec time! I would have expect to won some of the previous methods, with more Pythonic style. Good one @masmoudi . Method 3 matching lines: 16 - Exec time: 0.00037097930908203125

Comment: thanks glad you liked it. can you plz accept my answer that will make very happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try. It downloads raw YAML file from GitHub using [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/), parses the YAML using [`PyYAML`](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/), then checks the existence of each item from `absent` and `present` using [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and prints the lines that have all present items in the line and all absent items not in the line.

The YAML file is also downloaded in chunks, just in case it gets big. This is a good practice when downloading files over HTTP anyways.

**Demo:**

```
from pathlib import Path
from requests import get
from yaml import safe_load, YAMLError

def download_file(url, chunk_size=1024):
    with get(url, stream=True) as req:
        filename = Path(url).name
        with open(filename, mode="wb") as f:
            for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)

def parse_yaml_file(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        try:
            yaml_file = safe_load(f)
            return yaml_file
        except YAMLError as ex:
            print(ex)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    present = ['SYN', 'ACK']
    absent = ['RST', 'FIN']

    yaml_file = download_file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robcowart/elastiflow/master/logstash/elastiflow/dictionaries/tcp_flags.yml")

    data = parse_yaml_file(yaml_file)

    for number, line in data.items():
        if all(p in line for p in present) and all(a not in line for a in absent):
            print(f"{number}: {line}")
```

**Output:**

```
18: SYN-ACK
26: SYN-PSH-ACK
50: SYN-ACK-URG
58: SYN-PSH-ACK-URG
82: SYN-ACK-ECE
90: SYN-PSH-ACK-ECE
114: SYN-ACK-URG-ECE
122: SYN-PSH-ACK-URG-ECE
146: SYN-ACK-CWR
154: SYN-PSH-ACK-CWR
178: SYN-ACK-URG-CWR
186: SYN-PSH-ACK-URG-CWR
210: SYN-ACK-ECE-CWR
218: SYN-PSH-ACK-ECE-CWR
242: SYN-ACK-URG-ECE-CWR
250: SYN-PSH-ACK-URG-ECE-CWR
```

**Note:** The above will probably need more error checking for your scenario, but it shows the general idea.

Comment: Could the downvoter comment? This solution just adds code for getting the file from the GitHub link posted, and shows how to parse the YAML file into a list of dictionaries. I think that will be beneficial to the OP.

Comment: thank you @RoadRunner, super complete answer!!! I'll definitely use the part of downloading and parsing the YAML in the next days!!!. The exec time was the higher but still I'm surprised how low it was even downloading and parsing the file.         **Method 4-A (with download)** matching lines: 16 - Exec time: 0.08440136909484863  **Method 4-B (without download)** matching lines: 16 - Exec time: 0.0006995201110839844

Comment: @AdrianGiacometti No worries, I thought it would be useful. Apparently not so much by others, hence the downvote. The exec time will be a lot more when downloading. However,  The above download function is quite good since it performs well with even large files.